# How do I make the MATLAB code animate a bouncing ball

Tags: matlab, animation

```matlab
    close all;
    clear all;
    clc;
% height and period of time per data change
timeStep = 0.0005;
height = zeros(4e4,1);
% acceleration
g = 9.81;
% COR and initial height
COR = 0.8;
height(1)=15;
% initial speed
v = 0;


for i=2:length(height)
    v = v - g*timeStep;
    %new height
    height(i)=max(0,height(i-1)+v*timeStep);
    % stop ball from going below ground      
    if height(i)<=0
        % change velocity direction
        v = -COR*v;                      
    end

end  
% plot height on y and time on x axis
time = (1:4e4)*timeStep;
plot(time,height);
% turn into animation
%z = plot(time,height,'o','markerfacecolor','r','markersize',11);
i = 0;
while 1
    %set(z,'XData',time,'YData',height);
    %drawnow
    time2 = time(i);
    height2 = height(i);
    plot(time2,height2,'o','markerfacecolor','r','markersize',11);
    axis([0 15 0 15]);
    i = i + 1;
    pause(0.1);
end   
grid on; 
box on;
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want someone to rewrite your code to complete this homework? Or do you have a more specific question: maybe the program doesn't behave exactly like you expected, or maybe there's an error message, ... Please [edit] your post to include more information.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i would like someone to edit the last bit of the code around animating the ball. It won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted a small error. Your index `i` should start at 1 instead of 0.
Appart from that, all you need is update the graph with `drawnow`. The documentation can be found [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html).

As you provided this method within your comments I might suggest having a look at
`pause(0.1)` as this would mean your animation needs over 16 minutes to complete. There might have been updates on your graph without you noticing because of the small timestep.

Using the code you commented out this would be one possible solution.

```
% turn into animation
z= plot(time(1),height(1),'o','markerfacecolor','r','markersize',11);
axis([0 15 0 15]);
grid on;
box on;
for i = 2:length(height)
    set(z,'XData',time(i),'YData',height(i));
    drawnow limitrate
end
```